# Making an axis break

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, axis

so I'm working on a graph in `pgfplots` and in my data there is are a few outliers as you can see here[image]

so I was wondering how can I break the y axis as to enlarge the difference between the other 3 values. similar to this [image: enter code here]

Here my code so far

```latex
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis} [ylabel=$T_{pdr}/s$,xlabel=Transition$/ps$,legend pos=outer north east]
        \addlegendentry{$\mathrm{C}_{inv}$}
        \addplot table [x=Transition,y=tpdr,col sep = tab] {./data/complex/size1/cin1.csv};
        \addlegendentry{$2\mathrm{C}_{inv}$}
        \addplot table [x=Transition,y=tpdr,col sep = tab] {./data/complex/size1/cin2.csv};
        \addlegendentry{$4\mathrm{C}_{inv}$}
        \addplot table [x=Transition,y=tpdr,col sep = tab] {./data/complex/size1/cin4.csv};
        \addlegendentry{$8\mathrm{C}_{inv}$}
        \addplot table [x=Transition,y=tpdr,col sep = tab] {./data/complex/size1/cin8.csv};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. You could use a `groupplot` as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62778/ Edit: see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/359878/

Comment: Welcome! You will get better and more timely help if you post a complete minimal working example. I guess besides you not many users will have the data files you are using. You can use coordinate transformations to get the effect. (@TorbjørnT. Are you sure this post works also if the individual plots go in both or all three ranges?)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat On second thought, no. Didn't really think that one through ... (Abdelsalam: ignore at least my first link.)

Comment: Just looking at the plot I think there is a good chance that `ymode=log` will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do it to line chart.

```
\documentclass{minimal}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\tikzset{
    axis break gap/.initial=0mm
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    name=bottom axis,   
    legend cell align=left,
    width=14.3cm,
    height=4cm,
    xlabel = {X axis},
    xmin = 0, xmax = 10,     % Updated x-axis ranges for the bottom axis
    ymin = 38.5, ymax = 40.5,   % Updated y-axis ranges for the bottom axis
    ytick={38,39,40,41,42,43},       % Adjusted y-axis ticks
    grid = major,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    legend pos=south east,
]
\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=o,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1,74.05929323)(2,74.11004875)(3,73.83395062)(4,74.1121437)(5,74.04318766)(6,74.19709055)(7,74.08991301)(8,74.14607895)(9,74.20123279)
    };
    %\addlegendentry{Parameter1}
     
\addplot[
    color=red,
    mark=triangle,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1,73.90355191)(2,73.90355191)(3,73.90355191)(4,73.90355191)(5,73.90355191)(6,74.02102892)(7,74.01695258)(8,73.9599083)(9,73.96268008)
    };
    %\addlegendentry{Parameter2}

\addplot[
    color=green,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1,73.90355191)(2,73.90355191)(3,73.90355191)(4,73.90355191)(5,73.90355191)(6,74.21653139)(7,74.27160398)(8,74.34418505)(9,74.15820202)
    };
    %\addlegendentry{Parameter3}

\addplot[
    color=purple,
    mark=star,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1,70.78359818)(2,70.82715427)(3,70.88941587)(4,70.86594118)(5,70.72003935)(6,73.98564562)(7,73.87784185)(8,73.81499949)(9,73.91649512)
    };
    %\addlegendentry{Parameter4}

\addplot[
    color=orange,
    mark=diamond,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1,73.90355191)(2,73.90355191)(3,73.90355191)(4,73.90355191)(5,73.90355191)(6,73.10161425)(7,72.99986002)(8,72.80970372)(9,72.39335599)
    };
    %\addlegendentry{Parameter5}

\addplot[
    color=brown,
    mark=asterisk,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1,73.90355191)(2,73.90355191)(3,73.90355191)(4,73.90355191)(5,73.90355191)(6,73.7151607)(7,73.54188442)(8,73.65497217)(9,73.67833404)
    };
    %\addlegendentry{Parameter6}

\addplot[
    color=cyan,
    mark=oplus,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1,39.37007874)(2,39.37007874)(3,39.37007874)(4,39.37007874)(5,39.37007874)(6,45.5)(7,73.7824888)(8,73.72328176)(9,73.75368027)
    };
    %\addlegendentry{Parameter7}

\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
    at=(bottom axis.north),
    anchor=south, yshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/axis break gap},
    width=14.3cm,
    height=10cm,
    xmin = 0, xmax = 10,     % Updated x-axis ranges for the top axis
    ymin = 69, ymax = 75,   % Updated y-axis ranges for the top axis
    ytick={70,71,72,73,74,80},          % Adjusted y-axis ticks
    grid = major,
    ylabel = {Y axis},
    title = {Caption},  % Added title (topic)
    title style={yshift=-1ex, text centered},  % Center the title
    %legend entries = {excitatiespectrum},
    axis x line*=top,
    legend pos=south east,
    legend cell align=left,
    xticklabel=\empty,
    after end axis/.code={
         \draw (rel axis cs:0,0) +(-2mm,-1mm) -- +(2mm,1mm)
              ++(0pt,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/axis break gap})
              +(-2mm,-1mm) -- +(2mm,1mm)
              (rel axis cs:0,0) +(0mm,0mm) -- +(0mm,0mm)
              ++(0pt,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/axis break gap})
              +(-2mm,-1mm) -- +(2mm,1mm);
              \draw (rel axis cs:0,0) +(-2mm,0mm) -- +(2mm,2mm)
              ++(0pt,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/axis break gap})
              +(-2mm,-1mm) -- +(2mm,1mm)
              (rel axis cs:0,0) +(0mm,0mm) -- +(0mm,0mm)
              ++(0pt,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/axis break gap})
              +(-2mm,-1mm) -- +(2mm,1mm);
    }]

\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=o,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1,74.05929323)(2,74.11004875)(3,73.83395062)(4,74.1121437)(5,74.04318766)(6,74.19709055)(7,74.08991301)(8,74.14607895)(9,74.20123279)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Parameter1}
     
\addplot[
    color=red,
    mark=triangle,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1,73.90355191)(2,73.90355191)(3,73.90355191)(4,73.90355191)(5,73.90355191)(6,74.02102892)(7,74.01695258)(8,73.9599083)(9,73.96268008)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Parameter2}

\addplot[
    color=green,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1,73.90355191)(2,73.90355191)(3,73.90355191)(4,73.90355191)(5,73.90355191)(6,74.21653139)(7,74.27160398)(8,74.34418505)(9,74.15820202)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Parameter3}

\addplot[
    color=purple,
    mark=star,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1,70.78359818)(2,70.82715427)(3,70.88941587)(4,70.86594118)(5,70.72003935)(6,73.98564562)(7,73.87784185)(8,73.81499949)(9,73.91649512)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Parameter4}

\addplot[
    color=orange,
    mark=diamond,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1,73.90355191)(2,73.90355191)(3,73.90355191)(4,73.90355191)(5,73.90355191)(6,73.10161425)(7,72.99986002)(8,72.80970372)(9,72.39335599)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Parameter5}

\addplot[
    color=brown,
    mark=asterisk,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1,73.90355191)(2,73.90355191)(3,73.90355191)(4,73.90355191)(5,73.90355191)(6,73.7151607)(7,73.54188442)(8,73.65497217)(9,73.67833404)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Parameter6}

\addplot[
    color=cyan,
    mark=oplus,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1,39.37007874)(2,39.37007874)(3,39.37007874)(4,39.37007874)(5,67.9)(6,73.91158176)(7,73.7824888)(8,73.72328176)(9,73.75368027)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Parameter7}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Then download the generated PDF file and upload it to the original location of the main text file. And there you can add following code to generate high-quality image:

```
\begin{figure*}
\center
\includegraphics[scale=0.8, trim={3cm 16.5cm 4.5cm 2.2cm},clip]{Generated_Plot1.pdf }  
% trim from right edge
%\includegraphics[trim={0 0 5cm 0},clip]{SMOTE.pdf}
\caption{\label{schema}Caption 1}
\label{fig}
\end{figure*}
```

[image]

Finally you can see a continuous curve.