# How to plot broken axis in overleaf?

Tags: plot

I need to plot the following points in a plot: There is an outlier in Method 7, and hense I need to draw a broken y axis in the plot. How do I do it?

in the x axis, it should be [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

[image]

```
| Method | Method 1    | Method 2    | Method 3    | Method 4    | Method 5    | Method 6    | Method 7    |
|--------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|
| 1      | 76.73681516 | 76.89249513 | 76.89249513 | 76.45630787 | 76.89249513 | 76.89249513 | 26.92307692 |
| 2      | 76.79942315 | 76.65225307 | 76.64530852 | 76.35119861 | 76.91573489 | 76.68014282 | 76.67752768 |
| 3      | 76.67571204 | 76.55799935 | 76.67989418 | 76.20439599 | 76.66380503 | 76.77646095 | 76.36391707 |
| 4      | 76.80033767 | 76.74101365 | 76.61874249 | 76.61547225 | 76.64499213 | 76.80835399 | 76.4623643  |
| 5      | 76.76936705 | 76.67880746 | 76.68152023 | 76.617518   | 76.79432683 | 76.77737611 | 76.55552176 |
| 6      | 76.83263489 | 76.64698298 | 76.68152023 | 76.89467945 | 76.67257471 | 76.77737611 | 76.58433765 |
| 7      | 76.80603057 | 76.64698298 | 76.74568766 | 97.02083057 | 76.36040959 | 76.77737611 | 76.52309376 |
| 8      | 76.73939746 | 76.58355161 | 76.71349001 | 76.8011621  | 76.36179072 | 76.74584886 | 76.61138777 |
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should probably show what you tried so far because there are different ways to plot data using (La)TeX. Did you see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46422/47927 ?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/539361/making-an-axis-break/702107#702107